# Start an ac simulation at f=0Hz

Tags: ltspice, simulation

I would like to know please why is it that I can't start an .ac LTSpice simulation at f= 0Hz. I would like to know the DC impedance (or the equivalent resistance of my circuit that also contains inductors and capacitors) of my system. Any workarounds?

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Because DC is not AC.

Comment: If you want the DC response, do a DC analysis. If you want an AC response, then use a finite frequency, where things like capacitor impedance = 1/sC are finite.

Comment: @Neil_UK that is exactly what i did ;) check my answer below. Thank you btw !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I've found the answer minutes after posting the question.
Although I don't know yet why LTSpice does not allow a 0Hz .ac simulation, I know how to extract the DC impedance of my circuit (or as others may call it: the resistance). I basically run my .ac simulation from 1Hz to my maximum frequency and at LF (low frequencies) get a constant value which is basically the equivalent resistance of my system :)
[image: The impedance of my circuit]

Edit:
Also, after the clarifications of @ Bimpelrekkie, the .ac simulation does not run at 0Hz because "it is a simulation of a linearized model of the circuit. The model of the circuit can change with the DC ( = 0 Hz) voltages and currents of the circuit, for example, the behavior of a transistor based amplifier can change depending on the DC biasing current. The linearized model is made for that DC current. Simulating at 0 Hz does not make sense then as that would change the model."

Hope I was clear enough for other users.

Comment: *I don't know yet why LTSpice does not allow a 0Hz .ac simulation* Because the AC simulation is a simulation of a **linearized** model of the circuit. The model of the circuit can change with the DC ( = 0 Hz) voltages and currents of the circuit, for example, the behavior of a transistor based amplifier can change depending on the DC biasing current. The linearized model is made for that DC current. Simulating at 0 Hz does not make sense then as that would change the model. As a workaround, an AC simulation at a very low frequency is often good enough, as you find in your answer.

Comment: You could also try tenths of Hz (e.g. 1mHz) as a starting value if you believe it may be worth it.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you for the explanation, should I edit my answer?

Comment: @edmz yes true. Thank you !

Comment: @Wallflower Your answer so your choice! Feel free to copy text from my comment. I think you can even accept your own answer and that's not lying because you learned something :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your kindness :)

Comment: I 2nd the idea regarding the 1millihertz.  I usually use a command like `.ac dec 1k 1m 1meg` to sweep from "DC" to 1megahertz.

Comment: You need to wait forever to see 0 Hz